# ModuleNotFoundError on installed python library usage

Tags: python, pypi

I have a python library for distance measuring called `spycio`. I used on a just-opened jupyter notebook by installing using command `!pip install spycio` and statement `import spycio`.

For some unknown reason to me, I receive the error log below:

```
!pip list

...
sphinxcontrib-websupport      1.1.0
spycio                        0.2.5
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.37
...
```

```
import spycio

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import spycio

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spycio'
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: [Don't show pictues of text](/help/how-to-ask). Hit the [edit] button and just put your error into you post as text, with code formatting to preserve the spacing and newlines. And then show the result of `!pip list` in text as well to show that the library is indeed in that list.

Comment: Try running in your notebook in a new cell `%pip install spycio`, restart the kernel, and then run the import statement. You should not be using `pip install` with an exclamation point in modern Jupyter. The magic install commands were added to get around problems with the exclamation point (see [second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) about that) and the magic versions insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that is underlying the active notebook. ...

Comment: <continued> See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install commands that overcome exclamation point shortcomings & install into the correct environment. There is a lot of outdated information out there about installation commands, and so keep that in mind that best practices change in open source software as the developers seek to overcome shortcomings of which they become aware and improve the overall experience. Consider the date of the posts and seek more recent coverage.

Comment: This work very well. May you post this explanation as the post answer for future developers. You can even frame it as a community answer. ^^